# float[] in a struct

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have a float constant in my struct

```
private struct MyStruct
{
  public const float[] TEST = new float[] {1,2};
}
```

The preceding was my first guess but doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Non null arrays can't be `const` since `null` is the only compiletime constant of that type. You need `static readonly`. But that doesn't give you deep immutability. So perhaps wrap it in a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot have a const float[]

Most commonly handled with some varient of

```
public static readonly float[] TEST = new float[] {1,2};
```

But that array isn't itself immutable, thus you often go along the lines of

```
public static readonly IList<float> TEST = new ReadOnlyCollectioN(new float[] {1,2});
```

Finally, the last option is to create your own immutable representation of a float[] that can be instantiated and provide the same actions as float[] without being modified.

Comment: what do you mean immutable and is that important?

Comment: @rod - I mean the underlying set of values that were represented by the float[] cannot be changed; thus I cannot alter TEST[0] = some new value. This is covered by the Array.AsReadOnly mentioned in the answer above or new ReadOnlyCollection mentioned here. In the most basic sense, immutable means once constructed, the internal state of the object won't change.

Comment: Got it thanks for the insight. I definitely don't want the value to change.

Answer (score 4):

No.  But you could do this:

```
private struct MyStruct
{
  public static readonly IList<float> TEST = Array.AsReadOnly(new float[] {1,2});
}
```

Not using `Array.AsReadOnly` means that people could not make `TEST` point to a different array, but the array you have assigned could have its contents changed.

Comment: +1 Array.AsReadOnly is a little cleaner; although if replacing a const, I might make static? (unless const was intended to identify immutable)

Comment: Yes, of course I meant to include `static`.  :)  Brain-keyboard interface not working so well today.

Answer (score 0):

Constant initializers have to be compile time constants

```
new float[] {1,2}
```

creates a new object at runtime, not compile time.  You can, however, make it a static readonly field, i.e.

```
public static readonly float[] TEST = new...
```

Comment: float[] is still mutable and not constant, must make sure ReadOnly otherwise not really const.

Comment: strictly speaking, making it a ReadOnlyCollection instance doesn't make it a const either - it just restricts the behavior that can be performed on it.

Comment: It doesn't make the array const in the sense of "values are substituted in at compile time" but it does make the array const in the sense of "its contents can't be changed" (barring any stupid reflection hacks, of course...).